# Ubuntu SSD not recognized by BIOS after installing Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd, windows-10, bios

my problem is the following:

I can't boot my ubuntu SSD anymore because there is no option for it in the BIOS or boot menu.

I'm having two SSDs in my PC. On one I firstly installed Windows, on the second one Ubuntu. The ubuntu SSD is a 2,5" Samsung SSD connected via SATA. Both Windows SSDs are a Kingston M.2 NVMe SSD (the old one) and a Samsung M.2 NVMe SSD (the new one).

Due to less memory I bought a new SSD for my Windows system, exchanged it with the windows SSD, which was too small, and installed windows 10 on this new SSD. The other one - containing ubuntu - was not touched.

To boot each of the two OSs in the past, I just took my choice in the boot menu. I choose the Windows or Ubuntu hard drive to boot.

But now the Ubuntu SSD is not recognized anymore. Only the new Windows SSD. In the partitioning tool in windows, I saw the the partitions on the ubuntu SSD are quite fine. I even inserted the old SSD and got into the boot menu. As always: Both SSD and OSs are shown and I could choose one.

But as soon as I exchange the old too small Windows SSD with the new one, I just see the Windows SSD and OS in the BIOS.

What's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Disable 'Secure Boot' in the UEFI (incorrectly also called BIOS ). I guess you had to enable it to install Windows.

Comment: Check motherboard manual. Most disable a SATA port if using M.2 ports.